# Allow IAP access but deny any other Instance listing on the portal

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I know how to Allow **IAP** access for a specific Instance. The instance on which **IAP** is enable is only listed in **IAP** Application. But when the same user logs in to the portal he is able to list all the Instance present in the project.

I want that the instance on which **IAP** is enable should only be listed on **GCP** portal. Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Access to an IAP-protected resource via IAP is controlled by [IAP Roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#cloud-iap-roles) that contain access permissions such as `iap.webServiceVersions.accessViaIAP`.

The rights to list objects, for example Compute Engine instances, are controlled by the IAM roles (Primitive, such as `Owner` or `Browser`, or Predefined, such as `Compute Viewer`) that contain permission `compute.instances.list`.

Therefore a user that is not granted network access to the IAP-protected resource via IAP, but is granted the `Viewer` role for example, may see objects in the GCP Console.

This can be changed by following the [Cloud IAM best practices](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/using-iam-securely) and assigning more granular roles and permissions.

See [Cloud IAM > Doc > Understanding roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles) for more details.

Comment: I am following the concept of least privileges. but for IAP compute.projects.get, compute.instance.get and compute.instance.list are required at project level and I am not able to figure out how these role can be used to restrict listing of VMs. Currently user can see all the VMs in the project from GCP console and from IAP interface(only windows VM).

I will repeat my requirement:
I want that user should only be able to list the VM on which he is allowed IAP permission.

Comment: That permissions are necessary to load the web page `GCP Console > Security > Identity-Aware Proxy`, i.e. those permissions should be granted to the people who manages IAP via GCP Console GUI. For regular users to access an IAP-protected instance, the `IAP-secured Tunnel User` role should be enough. [Managing access to IAP-secured resources > Roles](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/managing-access#roles).